How do I add a new function to all numbers in MiniScript?
In Miniscript, when working with Sprites, I find I have to convert radians to degrees and degrees to radians a lot. In most examples, one sees this as varDegrees*pi/180 and varRadians*180/pi. Fine, but it feels verbose and I have to remember which one is which, and if there is other math I have to make sure I don't otherwise mess it up.
I know I can put a "rad" function in my script, and do rad(varDegrees), but I want a more OO-looking solution that doesn't mess with the appearance of my dot-chains.
So, how can I add a "rad" and "deg" function, so it applies to any number variable? So I can, for example, do MySprite.rotation.rad.sin to get the sin of the sprite's rotation angle?

You can add functions to the "number" prototype map. The function can be used on any number variable. Note that the sin() and cos() functions are NOT part of the number's prototype, so we have to add them, too, to be able to express this fully as a dot function chain.
Near the top of your script, add this:
// convert number to radians

number.rad = function; return self*pi/180; end function
// convert number to degrees
number.deg = function; return self*180/pi; end function
// return sine of radians angle
number.sin = function; return sin(self); end function
// return cosine of radians angle
number.cos = function; return cos(self); end function

The self variable is created for you when you use "dot notation" to call this function, just as you asked:
We've used ";" to separate the parts of the function definition so we can put it all on one line, just for brevity.
d = 90
print d.rad.sin // result is 1

Again, note that we can't apply these to literal values, like 90.rad.sin. Literals are not objects in the same way as variables in MiniScript.
With a Sprite, we might see something like:
dx = MySprite.rotation.rad.sin
dy = MySprite.rotation.rad.cos

